# How do I get the output of a Linux System Call in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I've added a simple `helloworld` system call to my Linux Kernel.

**sys_helloworld**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void)
{
        printk("Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

It just print out `Hello world` to the kernel log.

I called `sys_helloworld` system call like so :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   long int a = syscall(314); // 314 is the line number of sys_helloworld in syscall table
   printf("System call sys_helloworld returned %ld\n", a);
   return 0;
}
```

Above program successfully prints `Hello world` in kernel log.

**My Question :**

How do I get the output of `sys_hello` (which prints `Hello world` to the kernel log) in my program?

Comment: I don't get the question. What do you want to get? Your syscall doesn't return `Hello world`, it returns 0.

Comment: I know. I want to get `Hello World` in my program. Not just return `0` or `-1`..

Comment: This has next to nothing to do with syscalls. How do you "return a string" from _any_ function in C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. It's just a simple test. I mean prints `Hello world` no return. Excuse me. Edited..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add two arguments to your syscall: a buffer to write to, and its size. Then you can use `snprintf()` to print whatever string you want. You just have to make sure to use the right syscall definition macro. Since you will want 2 arguments, we need `SYSCALL_DEFINE2` here:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* For snprintf() */
#include <sys/syscall.h> /* For SYSCALL_DEFINE* macros */
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(sys_helloworld, char *, buff, size_t, buff_sz)
{
        snprintf(buff, buff_sz, "Hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

For completeness, and depending on the context, you might want to change the return value to something that allows you to know whether the string was truncated or not.

User code could call it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   char buf[32];
   long int a = syscall(314, buf, sizeof(buf));
   printf("System call sys_helloworld returned %ld\n", a);
   printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
   return 0;
}
```

Note that it is generally better style to use the `SYSCALL_DEFINE*` macros to define your syscall, instead of manually typing in `asmlinkage long ....`, even for a syscall with no arguments (you would use `SYSCALL_DEFINE0`). These macros are defined in `include/sys/syscall.h`, and you should use them.