# C - syscall - 64-bit - pointer

Tags: c, system-calls, mmap

I am on 64-bit Linux x86. I need to execute `mmap` syscall using `syscall` function. `mmap` syscall number is 9:

```
printf("mmap-1: %lli\n", syscall(9,    0, 10, 3, 2 | 32, -1, 0));
printf("mmap-2: %lli\n", mmap(         0, 10, 3, 2 | 32, -1, 0));
```

However, when I run it, the `syscall` function gives wrong results.

```
mmap-1: 2236940288
mmap-2: 140503502090240

mmap-1: 3425849344
mmap-2: 140612065181696

mmap-1: 249544704
mmap-2: 139625341366272
```

`mmap` works just fine, but the "addresses" returned `syscall` result in `Segmentation fault`. The values from `syscall` seem to be cast to 32 bits or something.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see on the man page, `syscall` returns an `int`, not a `long long` or pointer...?!?

Comment: From the man page about `syscall()`'s return value `The return value is defined by the system call being invoked.  In
       general, a 0 return value indicates success.  A -1 return value
       indicates an error, and an error code is stored in errno.`. You might want to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828461/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-linux-system-call-in-c-c) and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) for more information.

Comment: @DevSolar That is true, I am using `gcc` now, however, in another project using Node.js gyp compiler I think the `syscall` returned 64-bit value and everything was working fine. In any case, what is the right wayt to execute "64-bit" syscall?

Comment: This [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) says syscall returns `long`

Comment: if it returns `long` then why do you print with `%lli`? `long`'s prefix is `l`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc because I want to see 64-bit value, I don't know how big `long` is.

Comment: If you don't know how big `long` is why don't just print the size out? If you want a 64-bit value then why use `long` without knowing it's enough for 64 bits or not? Use `int64_t` instead and print it with [`PRId64`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6299083/995714), or use `long long` and print with `%lld`. Printing with the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem: I was running `gcc` with `-std=c99` option, removing it solved the problem:

```
mmap-1: 139975263928320
mmap-2: 139975263924224
```

I guess, `-std=99` defines syscall as `int syscall()` and without it its `long syscall()`.

Comment: no, the `syscall` function is **not** a C function. It's a POSIX function so it's parameters and return type depend on POSIX standard, which doesn't change with C99

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc well I removed `-std=c99` from `gcc` arguments and now it returns 64-bit values

Comment: as I said, using the wrong format specifier is undefined behavior, anything can happen. `printf` is a variadic function and knows nothing about the type, hence requires the user to use the correct format

Answer (score -1):

In your `syscall()`, instead of passing in `0 (NULL)` for the first parameter, `addr`, pass some pointer you have declared previously. This way you can access the memory mapped by `mmap`. `mmap` function declaration:

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```